# Visual Studio Code is returning an intelephense 1008 error message

Tags: php, sql

I have created a function which is referencing the `$pdo` object (which has also been successfully applied in a previous function) but it is now returning a

> 'Undefined variable 'pdo'.intelephense(1008).

Does anyone know what this means or how it can be resolved?

the statement itself is:

```
$stmnt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT validationcode FROM User WHERE username = :username");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please show all the relevant code, including where `$pdo` is defined.

Comment: It means `$pdo` isn't defined. In order words you never declared or populated any variable called `$pdo` before this line. Or at least, if you did, it wasn't within the scope where you're trying to use it. From the single line of code you've provided, of course we cannot tell you what the real root cause is, we can only make these suggestions and tell you to go and check them.